# Testing the upper bound of a function accepting a number literal in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, floating-point

I have the following function in JavaScript:

```
//foo is a number literal
function MyFunc(foo) {
  if(foo%15 === 0) {
    console.log("bar");
  }
}
```

I want to test the behavior at or around the upper size limit of `Number` in JavaScript.

Now I know that `Number`s in JavaScript are IEEE 64-bit floating point numbers. I also know that IEEE floating point numbers have the concept of sub-normals, and that they lose accuracy significantly during mathematical operations at very large (and very small) values, so does it make more sense to aim for testing around the maximum normal number?

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper implementations of JavaScript will not experience any error evaluating `foo%15 == 0`, regardless of where the value of `foo` lies in the floating-point domain. This is essentially because the exact mathematical result of `a%b` is never greater than `a` and never greater than `b`, so it is always in a finer region of the floating-point format, so it can always be represented at least as finely as both `a` and `b`, and that is fine enough because subtracting any multiple of `b` from `a` never creates finer bits than are in `a` or `b`.

Subnormals exist only below (less in magnitude than) normal numbers, hence the prefix “sub”. The maximum finite normal number is the maximum finite number.

Comment: Thank you. Is the term "finer region" a standard mathematical adjective/noun pairing?

Comment: @Ben: It is descriptive English with a clear mathematical meaning. In the normal range, the exponent specifies scaling for the significand. In an interval with a lower exponent, the represented values are closer together than in an interval with a higher exponent, so the floating-point format is finer in the former interval.

Comment: I intuitively thought that if the result of the division required to get the remainder fell in the area with a higher exponent (and therefore low accuracy), the result of the operation might be inaccurate. I think the key point in your answer is "and that is fine enough because subtracting any multiple of b from a never creates finer bits than are in a or b." Any expansion on this would be very useful.

Comment: @Ben: The JavaScript `%` operator is required (by 11.5.3 of the [Ecma-262 standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm)) to calculate the remainder correctly based on the mathematical quotient, not a quotient calculated with only regular floating-point precision. The implementation is responsible for getting that right, even if it means using extra precision internally or using multiple steps.

Answer (score 0):

According to Wikipedia the maximum representable integer by a double-precision floating point number is 2^53 (9,007,199,254,740,992). This might be a useful upper bound for my test.

```
9,007,199,254,740,992%15 === 2 //obviously
```

Comment: The maximum representable integer in an IEEE-754 64-bit binary floating-point object is 2**1024-2**971, which is considerably larger than 2**53. 2**53 is merely the largest integer such that it and all smaller integers are representable.